# write auto backup system on a pen drive

Tags: backup, system, portability

I'm trying to write a backup system on a pen drive (flash/ CD / DVD, YouNameIt).
The System need to able to run automatically upon connection to a Drive (end goal and OS!) find set folder and copy anything and paste on the drive.

and as a bonus it will be awesome to eject on completion (plug and play and remove)!

OK! this is my challenge and I have no idea where to begin.

I'm open for suggestions:
like what is the best language use what ways are the best way to good. personal tips/ recommendations, thing I should avoid! pro tips etc.

ps: security == a personal computer! System I have access to are Windows 8, Linux Ubuntu, Android ICS.

//Bardia 'Luviz' Jedi

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/25071/how-to-run-a-script-when-a-specific-flash-drive-is-mounted

Comment: if Im was reading the link correctly it seam to that scrip is ran on the "OS" it self meaning and a before hand installation is needed, right!?
so if it works in this fashion it a good start but not good enough due to "perinstallation" meaning that I have to write a macro before the autorun is able to function!